# const foo = module.exports = yadablah(){}; Why the const foo before module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand the concept of module.exports as being a container object, with property exports, which is returned when required.

But what is the purpose of "const foo =" here?

edit:

(Module user.js)

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}
```

**Okay. That makes sense now that I typed out the context. I initially misread "*User*.findById" as a different var (const). That was embarrassing!**

Comment: Don't see much (if any) of a usecase for that. Can you share a more elaborated example where you've seen it.

Comment: @Daniel I made an edit. That was embarrassing!

Comment: That is horribly written. It would have been more readable, without losing any performance, to write that as: `const User = mongoose.model(...); User.getUserById = function (){...}; module.exports = User;` And it only costs **one** extra line.

Answer (score 0):

This is what module looks like:

```
var module = { 
      exports: {
         yadablah: function(){
           //code
         }
} };
```

`foo` and `module.exports` both reference to the same object here that is function

```
yadablah()
```